# linear maps and ranks

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T : V → V$ be a linear map, where $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space.
Then $T^2$ is defined to be the composite $T\circ T$ of T with itself, and similarly $T^{i+1} = T\circ T^i$
for all $i ≥ 1.$

 Suppose that $Rank(T) = Rank(T^2).$

I've showed $Im(T) = Im(T^2)$. And for $i ≥ 1,$ let $U_i: Im(T) → Im(T)$ be defined as the restriction of $T^i$ to the subspace $Im(T)$ of $V.$

I have proven $U_i$ is non singular.

Using all this i need to deduce that $Rank(T) = Rank(T^i)$ for all $i ≥ 1.$ 

 Any help ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have $\operatorname{Im}T=\operatorname{Im}T^2$, everything else becomes trivial:

$$\operatorname{Im}T^3 = T(\operatorname{Im}T^2) = T(\operatorname{Im}T) = \operatorname{Im}T^2=\operatorname{Im}T$$

And similiar $\operatorname{Im}T^i = \operatorname{Im}T$ by induction for all $i > 0$.

Comment: nice one (:Thanks

Comment: @Moos does it  mean that the $dim(Im(T))$=0 or 1?